# Can I catch SQL Server Events with TEventDispatcher via TADOConnection?

Tags: c++, sql-server, c++builder, com+, adoconnection

I'm trying to catch lost connection on `TADOConnection`.
I've read [this](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26734) and [that](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Handling_Events_in_an_Automation_Controller) article

I've implement `TEventDispatcher` class like that.

```
#include <utilcls.h>
#include <ADOInt.hpp>

class EventHandler : public TEventDispatcher<EventHandler,&DIID_ConnectionEvents>
{
private:
  bool connected;
  TForm1 *theform;
  _Connection* server;
protected:
  HRESULT InvokeEvent(DISPID id, TVariant *params);
public:
  EventHandler();
  ~EventHandler();
  void Connect(TForm1 *form, _Connection* srv);
  void Disconnect();
};

EventHandler::EventHandler()
{
  connected = false;
  theform = NULL;
}

EventHandler::~EventHandler()
{
  if (connected)
    Disconnect();
}
```

implementation

```
EventHandler *handler = new EventHandler();

HRESULT EventHandler::InvokeEvent(DISPID id, TVariant *params)
{
 String data = WideString(*params);
 ShowMessage("InvokeEvent : "+IntToStr(id)+" "+data);
}

void EventHandler::Connect(TForm1 *form, _Connection* srv)
{
  theform = form;

  server = srv;
  server->AddRef();
  ConnectEvents(server);
}

void EventHandler::Disconnect()
{
  DisconnectEvents(server);
  server->Release();
}
```

I'm trying to using EventHandler class like that.

```
handler->Connect(this,ADOConnection1->ConnectionObject);
```

Why don't call `InvokeEvent` method of `EventHandler` class when sql server manual stopped ?

Comment: bu aralar paso c++ heyirdir?

Comment: You cannot expect to receive notifications of unexpected events in this way. The connectionLost event will be fired only when the client KNOWS that the connection is lost. This may not be for some time after the actual loss of connection.

Comment: @Ben thanks for your comment.
Can you give me alternative solution about this ?